# Update the training accuracy to the front end

Tags: python, tensorflow, asynchronous, flask, keras

I am doing a web app , when the button is clicked newly updated data will be trained. When the training is on progress, I should show the  progress on the the front end. Progress means for every epoch I should show the accuracy and error level. I could easily get it from keras but How to update it in the front end.

I am using KERAS for the model training and FLASK framework for the web. Is there any one face the same problem as me.

Comment: If you don't need it to be efficient then you can write the results to JSON file and update values in the front end from that file. Probably AJAX if you do not want to refresh the page.